# Authorization in OneDrive with C#

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth, authorization, onedrive

Someone knows how to make the authorization in OneDrive without oAuth?
I need to make an application that will sign with my name.
That when downloading an application has already been made authorization.
Hellp PLS!

Comment: The OneDrive API only supports OAuth.

Comment: @Toan-Nguyen Thank you! I thought so:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Code Flow](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm) model to achieve that. You just need to get a refresh_token and store it in your application settings.